# Get Monaco Editor CodeLens info on click

Tags: monaco-editor

Using this [CodeLens provider example](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-codelens-provider-example) as a starting point, I've been trying to figure out how to get the range information associated with the CodeLens when the link is clicked.

```
var commandId = editor.addCommand(0, function() {
    // services available in `ctx`
    alert('my command is executing!');

}, '');

monaco.languages.registerCodeLensProvider('json', {
    provideCodeLenses: function(model, token) {
        return [
            {
                range: {
                    startLineNumber: 1,
                    startColumn: 1,
                    endLineNumber: 2,
                    endColumn: 1
                },
                id: "First Line",
                command: {
                    id: commandId,
                    title: "First Line"
                }
            }
        ];
    },
    resolveCodeLens: function(model, codeLens, token) {
        return codeLens;
    }
});
```

I'm unsure as to what the `ctx` comment refers to. I've tried adding this as a parameter to that anonymous function parameter in `addCommand`, but I haven't got anything from it. Is it even possible to get that range information specified in the `provideCodeLenses` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, I added an `arguments` property to the `command` property of the returned object in `provideCodeLenses`:

```
provideCodeLenses: function(model, token) {
    return [
        {
            range: {
                startLineNumber: 1,
                startColumn: 1,
                endLineNumber: 2,
                endColumn: 1
            },
            id: "First Line",
            command: {
                id: commandId,
                title: "First Line",
                arguments: { from: 1, to: 2 },
            }
        }
    ];
}
```

This can then be accessed in the `addCommand` anonymous function:

```
var commandId = editor.addCommand(0, function(ctx, args) {
    console.log(args); // { from: 1, to: 2 }
}, '');
```